# Chrome Storage returning undefined when default value is undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

Example code:

```
await (new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        chrome.storage.local.get({
            [STORAGE.KEY]: false  // or anything different than undefined
        }, function(items) {
            if( ! chrome.runtime.lastError){
                resolve(items[STORAGE.KEY]);
            }
            else {
                reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }
        });
    }))
```

That works without problems. But if I change the default value to **undefined**, then it always returns undefined, no matter if there is some value in the storage.

I was fighting with this until noted the problem, but I'm not sure if this is a bug from Chrome or some bad design from my side.

Comment: This is how the API works. There's nothing you can do except for not using `undefined`.

Comment: yes, I will avoid using undefined as default value, but I couldn't find any reference to that in the docs, do you have the link explaining that?

Comment: The storage supports JSON-ifiable data which doesn't include `undefined`.

Comment: but I'm not setting any value, is a default value for get, anyway, maybe is related with that, thanks

Comment: You're setting the value to `undefined` which is not a JSON-compatible value.

Comment: I'm not setting it @wOxxOm, is a "get" method, and the first param is the default value in case the key is not present in local storage, but if you put undefined to the default value then it returns always undefined even if the key exists! https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#method-StorageArea-get

Comment: You're setting the object's property to the value of `undefined`.

Comment: Like I said, this is how it works. You'll have to use a different value, not `undefined`.